# Changing files in place with gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a gulp task that looks like this:

```
gulp.task('htmlServer', ['bower'], function(cb) {
  return gulp.src(config.build.htmlServerFiles, {base: './'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build.build));
});
```

It just moves some files around.  The bower task makes some changes to these files in place.

```
  gulp.task('bower', ['jadeServer'], function() {
    gulp.src(path.join(config.build.basepath, 'public/index.html'))
      .pipe(wiredep({
        directory: path.join(config.build.basepath, 'public/bower_components/'),
        bowerJson: require(path.join(config.build.basepath, './bower.json'))
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(config.build.basepath, 'public')));
  });
```

Unfortunately, the `htmlServer` task seems to move a version of the files that existed prior to the changes made by the `bower` task.

What am I doing wrong?  Can I not change files in place?

Answer (score 1):

Your 'bower' task must return its built pipe, otherwise it cannot signal when it's done and so the tasks are run in parallel.

See second example in https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del'); // rm -rf

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del(['output']);
});

gulp.task('templates', ['clean'], function() {
    var stream = gulp.src(['src/templates/*.hbs'])
        // do some concatenation, minification, etc.
        .pipe(gulp.dest('output/templates/'));
    return stream; // return the stream as the completion hint

});
```